# Multiple controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

This is a general question. I am forced to have a single controller in my codeigniter application because everything works fine locally and i get errors while moving my files from localhost to live server for example 404 error while trying to access a controller from a submit button in the view. what is the best practice or the best tutorials to build a multiple controller codeigniter app without running into problems from URL's and .htaccess files.

Comment: If your problem come from your htaccess, try to resolve it by yourself. Just search "codeigniter htaccess" on Google. Did you change the main URL in your config file when you put it on your server ?

Comment: problems comes in migrating from localhost to live server.It's recommended  that you properly configure your CI files set the proper base url,default controller has been set as your need

Comment: yes.. i have updated base_url()

Comment: its always difficult to solve problems with half knowledge of wats happening ... is there any tutorials which gives in depth explanation on how everything functions one at a time..

Comment: @shank can you please update you code of your controller??

Comment: try to access your controllers in this way maybe solve your issue. `localhost/abc/controller` => `localhost/abc/index.php/controller` if it's work the issue with your .htaccess file.